# How to create username in codeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, user-profile

I want address of my website user is mydomain.com/username/. But it seems very difficult to me using codeIgniter.Please help me what is best way to do it.

mysite.com/profile?user=username 
is current url of profile but i want this
   mysite.com/username

please help me and I'm not good english speaker so I'm sorry if you not understand my question.

Answer (score 2):

In your `routes.php` file route every existing controller (you should have atleast one) to itself. For example if you have controller `main` in `main.php` file route it:

```
$route['main'] = "main";
$route['main/(:any)' = "main/$1";
```

The reason why you should route it twice is because you must make sure that opening `http://yoursite/main` works as well as `http://yoursite/main/my_method/` etc. Do this for every other controller you have.

The next step is to route everything else to your users controller. For example you have a `profile` method that has 1 argument - the username.

```
$route['(:any)'] = "users/profile/$1";
```

So now you will have everything else routed to `users/profile/username`.

One thing to remember is that the topmost priority goes higher in the `routes.php` file so your routes file should look something like:

```
$route['main'] = "main";
$route['main/(:any)' = "main/$1";
$route['users'] = "main";
$route['users/(:any)' = "main/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "users/profile/$1";
```

See if that works!

Comment: I can't believe it really works, You explained very well thanks Vlakarados. One thing I still have confusion is that what if a user registers with a name like "logout" and I have "logout" controller too. ??? Hope you will also help me in this issue

Comment: That's the matter of logic, if you will really allow him to do it, he won't be able to see his profile. If you wont it to be the other way, you can move line `$route['(:any)'] = "users/profile/$1";` to the beginning of the file. I would filter all usernames like that. Logout, login, exit, function some other keywords too. If you have a full domain for this project, you can always use subdomains and make profiles there. For example you have your fully functional portal at `yourdomain.com` so you can make an app at `users.yourdomain.com/ejaz_karim`

Comment: But anyway, see how, for example facebook does it, they have `facebook.com/some_username` and `facebook.com/messages`, so I think they just don't allow to have such usernames.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CI [routing](http://www.codeigniter.fr/user_guide/general/routing.html)

In your route.php file, select all your users and create a route for each :

```
$aUsers = $this->oDb->getAllUsers();
foreach($aUsers as $oUser) {
    $route[$oUser->username] = "profile/" . $oUser->username;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: It will not work at it should not work either. Routing is loaded before most of the other CodeIgniter files like database library and everything else. Only thing you can do to make your solution work is to write a query to MySQL without CodeIgniter in pure PHP, but that's ridiculous.

Comment: I not agree. I'm using this patch on two websites, you just have to share a DBManager (a singleton for instance) and to load in the route.php file. You don't need more CI libs or plugins for that.

Comment: Well yes, if you use third-party libraries/classes, of course you can just do a `require_once();` in index.php and this will work, but this looks like a hack. The only way you can do this to be more of a CodeIgniter style is to use the `pre_system` hook, as it's run just before routes are parsed.